# Uniqueness of Borel sigma algebra on X

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

I have a question about the uniqueness of $\mathcal{B}(X)$, Borel sigma algebra on X. Suppose $A\subseteq X$, then is $\{\varnothing, A, A^c, X\}$ a Borel sigma algebra on X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Borel $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) is defined in terms of a [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology#Topologies_on_sets) on $X$. Indeed, it's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the opens. That is, if $\tau$ is a topology on $X$, then $\mathcal{B}(X,\tau)$ is the (unique) smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\tau$.

So to ask what the Borel algebra on $X$ is, without first fixing a topology on $X$, is a meaningless question.

That said, there are topologies on $X$ for which $\{\emptyset, A, A^c, X\}$ is the whole Borel algebra. Can you find one? As a hint, you shouldn't have to change much...

As one last aside, you might ask if *every* $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$ is the Borel algebra for some topology on $X$. It turns out (surprisingly, I think!) that the answer is "no". See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87838/is-every-sigma-algebra-the-borel-algebra-of-a-topology) for more information.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Is it $\tau=\{\varnothing, A, A^c, X\}$? Are there different topologies? Sorry, I can see the only one.

Comment: Yes! $\tau = \{\emptyset, A, A^c, X\}$ works. I'll tell you that there's $2$ more that work as well. They require _slightly_ more work, but not by much. Can you find them too?

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Comment: I guess it is related with the boundary of set $A$, but I am not sure. By the way, I see $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ without claiming its topology. Is there something assumed and omitted? I am reading some papers about stochastic processes. They claimed $\mathcal{B}(X)$ without the topology. It makes me really confused.

Comment: Hi, Halla. I think the other two topologies are $\tau_1=\{\varnothing, A, X\}$ and $\tau_2=\{\varnothing, A^c, X\}$.

Comment: Nailed it ^_^ ${}$